# Max-height value is wrong on Chrome but it's OK on Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, cross-browser

I've recently updated Chrome from 95.0.4638.69 to 96.0.4664.45

Before the update everything was working correctly but after the update max-height value is wrong.

This is on Firefox which is works correctly:

[image]

This is updated Chrome which is works wrong:

[This is updated Chrome which is works wrong:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BHvi2.png)

Are there anyone who encountered this problem too?
Thank you all.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I am not that sure about how this works on firefox but I think it has something to do with firefox having a smaller UI while google takes up more space on the screen. You might be able to use media screens here but I think it should work. Or if you are mainly going to use chrome then just set the height to what suits chrome.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It was working well on older version of Chrome so I don't think it's related with that.

Comment: Yes but google might have updated their UI too.